# Adding a line at the beginning of the file with values computed from date

Tags: text-processing, date

I am using Solaris O/S.
Here are the basic stats for UNIX O/S I am using:

```
$ oslevel
7.1.0.0
$ ps
      PID    TTY  TIME CMD
 10944546  pts/1  0:00 -ksh
 17563840  pts/1  0:00 ps
$
```

I am need to write a text on the first line of a text file

```
test.txt
```

Text I need to add to the first line on `test.txt` is

MHHHRGFILE (sysdate - First day of 9 months) 99991231

For middle part 
(sysdate - First day of 9 months), for eg. Today's date is 07/26/2017, I will need to minus 9 months and then first day of that month. Meaning, I will need to print 20161001

Basically I will end up writing:

```
MHHHRGFILE 20161001 99991231
```

to the first line of the file `test.txt` where MHHHRGFILE and 99991231 are staying constant all the time.

Comment: The command `oslevel` and its output of 7.1.0.0 make that look a lot like an AIX system, not a Solaris one.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solaris/Aix date

Sadly, there is no solution possible with (only) Solaris/Aix date.

#### GNU date

If gnu date is available:

Build the date needed in a variable:

```
$ date +'%Y/%m/01 -9 months'
2017/07/01 -9 months
$ a=$(date +'%Y/%m/01 -9 months')
$ a=$(date -d "$a" +'%Y%m%d')
$ a='MHHHRGFILE ('"$a"') 99991231'
$ echo "$a"
MHHHRGFILE (20161001) 99991231
```

Or simply:

```
$ a=$(date -d "$(date +'%Y/%m/01 -9 months')" +'%Y%m%d')
$ a='MHHHRGFILE ('"$a"') 99991231'
```

#### Bash

If bash (4.2+) is available:
(using 272 days as equivalent to 9 months)

```
$ TZ=UTC0 printf '%(%Y%m01)T' $(($(date +'%s') - 3600*24*272))
20161001

$ a=$(TZ=UTC0 printf '%(%Y%m01)T' $(($(date +'%s') - 3600*24*272)))
```

#### ksh93

If the ksh is available:

```
$ printf "%(%Y%m%d)T" "9 month ago"
```

#### Perl

If perl is available (9 months are aproximated with 3600*24*30*9):

```
$ perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%Y%m01",localtime(time()- 3600*24*30*9);'
20161001

$ a=$(perl -e 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%Y%m01",localtime(time()- 3600*24*30*9);')
```

#### Edit the file

Append that variable to the first line of `file`

```
$ sed '1s/.*/&'"$a"'/' file >file.new; mv file.new file
```

That's it.

Comment: Here is my script:#!/bin/ksh

date +'%Y/%m/01 -9 months'
a=$(date +'%Y/%m/01 -9 months')
a=$(date -d "$a" +'%Y%m%d')
echo "$a"   it errors like this :$ ./add*
2017/07/01 -9 months
date: Not a recognized flag: d
Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]

Comment: You do not have the GNU version of date. Your version of date does not have a `-d` option.  Do you have an usable perl installed? Or, could you install a program in the computer ?  Then install (and use) GNU date.

Comment: @user3519878 Added a Bash based solution, it may be useful.

Comment: No `sed -i` in AIX or Solaris. You can use `perl -lpi -e '$_ .= $ENV{VAR}' if $. == 1'` (GNU `sed`'s `-i` was inspired from `perl`'s)

Comment: I should have tested it before posting. I believe it is working now. Thanks @StéphaneChazelas

Answer (score 1):

It's not complicated to do by hand here:

```
eval "$(date +'y=%Y m=%m')"
m=$((${m#0} - 9)) # need to strip the 0 for shells like bash or some 
                  # ash derivatives (but not ksh) that complain
                  # about an invalid 09 octal number in arithmetic
                  # expressions. Some date implementations support
                  # date +%-m, but that's not standard.
if [ "$m" -le 0 ]; then
  m=$((m + 12)) y=$((y - 1))
fi
if [ "$m" -lt 10 ]; then
  m=0$m # 0-pad single-digit numbers
fi
sed "1s/$/MHHHRGFILE $y${m}01 99991231/" < file > newfile
```

Comment: Thanks Stephane Chazelas It works till if loop and prints right characters but it is not writing to a file:(  I got error message like this:file: 0403-016 Cannot find or open the file.

Comment: Here is my script:  #!/bin/ksh

eval "$(date +'y=%Y m=%m')"
m=$((${m#0} - 9))

if [ "$m" -le 0 ]; then
  m=$((m + 12)) y=$((y - 1))
fi

echo "$m"
prvdt=$y${m}01
echo $prvdt
a='MHMRFILE '"$prvdt"' 99991231'
echo $a
sed '1s/.*/&'"$a"'/' file >filename_I_want_to_enter_This_text.txt Errors: sed: 0602-419 Cannot find or open file file.

Comment: Your function fails to add a required `0` to months under `10`. Probably a missing `printf '%02d' "$m"`

Comment: @Arrow, well spotted, thanks. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final script that works and outputs Text and Date (go back 9 months and picks first day of that month) into a file on "solaris AIX" Kshell.

```
#!/bin/ksh

eval "$(date +'y=%Y m=%m')"
m=$((${m#0} - 9))

if [ "$m" -le 0 ]; then
  m=$((m + 12)) y=$((y - 1))
fi

echo "$m"
prvdt=$y${m}01
echo $prvdt
a='MHHHRGFILE '"$prvdt"' 99991231'
echo $a


var="$a"
echo $var
destdir=/applic/e396/data/NNA/Dclients_for_FPD.txt
echo 'Destination File is locate at' $destdir

echo $var >> $destdir
```

The only issue I am having it add's text `MHHHRGFILE 20161001 99991231` at the end of file while i need to add it at very top as a first line item.

Please let me know/help my code correctly so It writes output into destination file's first line.

Comment: The calculation fails to add a leading 0 if the resulting month is 9 or less.